# Jenkins start JBOSS inside of a job and go on

Tags: jboss, jenkins, hudson

I have a Jenkins job where I want to

```
- build my application 
- start the jboss via batch
- sleep some time to wait for the jboss
- do some junit tests
- stop the jboss
```

The problem I have is that the job does not proceed after the jboss start. It shows the complete jboss log and just keeps refreshing this log.
So the sleep and junit tests are never executed.

batchcall im using:

```
cmd.exe /C F:\jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6\bin\run.bat -c Servername -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-05 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

I can't use the jenkins jboss management plugin because i have to set java_opts for this specific job.

Any idea how to start the Jboss without showing the log in the jenkins console?

**EDIT :**

Thanks for your answer, but call/start didn't work for me either.

My working solution:
(not nice but it works, just thought i should share it)

- I created a 2nd Jenkins job which starts the JBoss with the batch call from above.
- Then changed this job to be triggered remotely. "Trigger builds remotely"
- Now i changed my 1st job to trigger the 2nd in a build step "Execute batch command"

  - wget --spider build_trigger_url

So my Job is doing this now:

- build my application
- trigger the jboss jenkins job via wget

  - this 2nd job is now also running on jenkins, until it is manually shut down
- sleep some time, until the jboss is started
- execute junit tests
- stop the jboss

  - via jboss management plugin, this kills the 2nd job

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to `cmd.exe /C call F:\jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6\bin\run.bat <whatever params>`

When you trigger a `.bat` it passes control to it and runs it until the `.bat` terminates. Instead, you need to spawn off another process to run the `.bat`. This is done with `call` command.